# Cannot access GUI in Ubuntu 18.04 after a CUDA version update and Nvidia driver update

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, ubuntu-18.04, recovery

After installing a Nvidia driver, I cannot access my Ubuntu 18.04 GUI anymore. Now, it seems as I have only access to the recovery mode.

I required to update my CUDA version and I, probably, purged one module too many.

In the beginning, neither my keyboard nor my mouse was working and I used another Linux kernel to login. Then, I have seen that my GPU was not recognized and I decided to reinstall NVIDIA and CUDA drivers (downloading the .run files and executing them with `sudo sh ./file.run`. This has now wrecked my access to the OS.

Booting my system gives me the following text (N,M,L,K and X are placeholders for numbers):

```
Warning: Failed to connecct to lvmetad; Falling back to device scanning
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, N/M files, L/K blocks
[ X] nvidia-gpu 0000:07:00:3: i2c timeout error e000000
```

Using in the recovery mode,`sudo apt install` commands or the `dpkg      Repair broken packages` throw `Failed to fetch` errors.
I have also tried `sudo apt purge nvidia*`, without success.

How can I install or access a GUI again? How would it be possible to connect to one of the repositories to install packages?

Answer (score 0):

It migjt be useful to include more info in your question. How did you install the drivers? What kernels are you using, how did you install them?

You should try to purge all nvidia-
related software (drivers & CUDA) by running `sudo apt purge nvidia*`.
After that, you should be able to login to GUI even if you dont have the appropriate drivers. You can then try to install nvidia drivers again - I recommend downloading the official cuda.deb package on nvidia website and installing it with `dpkg -i`.

Comment: I have tried that already, I think the purge command finally demolished the access to the gui. I have updated my question, but if there is still something missing, I'll add it gladly!

Comment: Did you uninstall anything else when purging nvidia? Kernels might also be the problem here.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. In the meanwhile, I saved my files and re-installed ubuntu. Thanks anyways for your help!